# Android ScrollView verticalScrollbarPosition property

Tags: android, position, scrollview, scrollbar

I use verticalScrollbarPosition="left" as property of ScrollView and it works fine and positions vertical scrollbar to the left of view. But in the Android Developers Documentation there is no any property named verticalScrollbarPosition!

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a part of the `View` class documentation found here [View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT)

```
SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT
added in API level 11
public static final int SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT
Position the scroll bar along the left edge.

Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Try including a snippet of what's located at the site you link to, just in case the site ever goes down.

Comment: Thanks. For API less than 11 isn't it applicable? Is there a backward compatibility for it?